# Jquery in php issue

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, curl

I'm using Zend framework and php to fetch output from an API using cURL. I have an ajax/jquery part wherein I have made the output appear on a different window by the following jquery code snippet:

```
success:function(ret){

                var win = window.open();
                win.document.write(ret);
            }
```

The output comes up. However, the new window in which the output is displayed keeps on loading and never stops. I want to know how to stop it from keeping on loading.
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this after you write to the window:

```
win.document.close();
```